# Removing line for binary predictors in a marginal effects plot using plot_model

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I'm trying to produce a marginal effects plot from a logistic regression I ran, using plot_model (sjPlot), from publicly available survey data. The predictor for the plot is binary (male or female) and the response variable is whether a respondent votes for a Green party.

This is the code:

```
logit3 %>%
  plot_model(
    type = "pred",
    terms = "female"
  ) +
  labs(
      x = "Gender",
      y = "Predicted probability of voting Green",
      title = "Predicted probability of voting Green by gender"
  )
```

And this is the plot:

[image]

The plot produces fine but, since this is a binary predictor, I would like it as two separate points (for male and female), with confidence intervals, rather than than a linear line between the two.

I'm sure this has an easy answer and that I'm just being stupid, but I can't seem to find anything online. I also haven't posted much on this forum, so please let me know if I need to provide anything else.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a simple reproducible example.

Comment: If you set up your regression with `female` as a factor, `plot_model` will recognize that and plot correctly. Here's an actual reproducible example: `library(sjPlot); mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am); m <- glm(vs ~ am, mtcars, family = 'binomial'); plot_model(m, type = "pred", terms = "am")`

Comment: @Axeman post as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not posting a reprex. Specifying the predictor using factor() solved the problem, thank you! I had previously tried using as.factor(), which didn't work.

```
library(sjPlot) 
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am)
m <- glm(vs ~ am, mtcars, family = 'binomial')
plot_model(m, type = "pred", terms = "am")
```